# Positive integers $a,b$ satisfying $a^3+a+1=3^b$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

How to prove that $a=b=1$ is the only positive integer solution to the following Diophantine equation?$$a^3+a+1=3^b$$

Comment: "seemingly easy..." It doesn't look easy to me at all. On one side we have a polynomial of degree 3, and on the other we have a variable in exponential. So at least at the first glance it looks _hard_.

Comment: To get a partial solution, look at the problem $\mod 3$.  The right hand side $\mod 3$ is clearly $0$, so we know that each term of the left hand side $\mod 3$ will add up to $0\mod 3$.  Because of the $1$ on the left hand side, we know that $(a^3+a)\mod 3=2\mod 3$.  Now, assume that $a=3k+c$ where $c\in\{0,1,2\}$.  If $c=0$ then $(a^3+a)\mod 3=0\neq 2$, a contradiction.  If $c=2$ you get that $(a^3+a)\mod 3=1\neq 2$ (after a bit of algebra).  $c=1$ leads to $(a^3+a)\mod 3=2$, which is what you want.  From this, you can show $a=3k+1$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I got this conclusion, but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Sorry but my answer is wrong.

Comment: @Ghartal please remove your accept of my answer. I cannot delete my answer

Comment: Yes. Wojowu said there will be arbitarily large powers by hensels lemma

Comment: I have reduced the cases to $a \equiv 1 \pmod {12}$ and $b \equiv 1 \pmod {2}$. However, this case is proving more difficult than initially imagined.

Comment: I got also $a \equiv 7 \pmod 9$. But as you mentioned these are not very useful!

Comment: Did you invent the problem or does it have some other source? And do you already know that it has no other solutions, or is it just a conjecture?

Comment: I should have mentioned this. I came up with this solving another Diophantine equation. It is a conjecture.

Comment: One could use, say Magma, to find the integral points on the elliptic curves $y^2=a^3+a+1$ and $3y^2=a^3+a+1$.

Comment: Sir, how this will help us?

Comment: Well, the exponent $b$ is either even or odd.

Comment: Good point sir. Thank you :) To my knowledge there are no elementary methods to find integral points on elliptic curves. So the problem is still open!

Comment: I give up. Actually, this is a problem about integer points in an  elliptic curve and  we know that is a bigger problem.Only it is known that when there are solutions its are in finite number (but finite just means not infinite....till I know it is not stablished a bound for this)

Comment: Agreed. I give up too.

Comment: It is easy to see by induction that $3^n>n^3+n+1$ for $n\ge4$.

Comment: Don't give up so easily. The equations $y^2=a^3+a+1$ and $3y^2=a^3+a+1$ have probably been studied and their solutions tabulated and posted to the web or published in some journal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $a=b=1$ is the only solution.

As **Mike Bennett** suggests in the comments,
this can be proved by asking more generally for
integer points on the elliptic curves $y^2 = x^3 + x + 1$ [for $b$ even,
with $(x,y) = (a,3^{b/2})$] and $3y^2 = x^3+x+1$ [for $b$ odd, with
$(a,y) = (a,3^{(b-1)/2})$].
[Siegel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%27s_theorem_on_integral_points) shows that there are
only finitely many solutions; his proof is ineffective, but
since then new techniques have been developed and implemented to 
provably list all solutions.

As **Gerry Myerson** suggests in *his* comment, these curves
are simple enough that the computation of their integer points
has already been done.  These days the most extensive online databases
for such results are collected in the LMFDB,
so I looked there.

The first curve, $y^2 = x^3 + x + 1$, is 
[496.a1](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/496/a/1);
there are two pairs of integral points, $(0,\pm 1)$ and $(72,\pm 611)$.
Only the first makes $y$ a power of $3$, and gives the solution $(a,b)=(0,0)$,
which is integral, but not positive as **Ghartal** asks.

The second curve, $3y^2 = x^3 + x + 1$, is not in Weiestrass form,
but we can take $X=3x$ and find that 
$$
X^3+9X+27 = 27(x^3+x+1) = 81y^2 = (9y)^2,
$$
so $(3x,9y)$ is an integral point on the curve $Y^2 = X^3 + 9X + 27$.
This is curve
[2232.j1](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/2232/a/1)
in the LMFDB; its only integral points are $(X,Y) = (-2,\pm1)$ and $(3,\pm9)$.
The former yields $(a,b) = (-2/3,-3)$, a rational solution but again
not satisfying **Ghartal**'s condition that $a,b$ be positive integers.
The latter yields the known solution $(a,b)=(1,1)$.

This completes the determination of solutions of $a^3+a+1 = 3^b$
in positive integers.

It may be quite hard to give an elementary proof; e.g. once we have the
nontrivial solution with $b=1$ it's impossible to exclude further 
solutions by congruence conditions alone (congruence modulo
powers of $3$ only impose conditions on $a$ modulo powers of $3$,
which cannot combine with congruences to moduli coprime with $3$
to give a contradiction).

Answer (score 1):

Partial solution, Check the equation mod 9 $\big(\forall b>1,3^b\equiv 0 \pmod 9\big)$. Nine cases to check:
$a=0 \pmod 9, a^3+a+1\equiv 1 \pmod 9\\ 
a=1 \pmod 9, a^3+a+1\equiv 3 \pmod 9 \\
a=2 \pmod 9, a^3+a+1\equiv 2 \pmod 9\\
a=3 \pmod 9, a^3+a+1\equiv 4 \pmod 9\\
a=4 \pmod 9, a^3+a+1\equiv 6 \pmod 9\\
a=5 \pmod 9, a^3+a+1\equiv 5 \pmod 9\\
a=6 \pmod 9, a^3+a+1\equiv 7 \pmod 9\\
a=7 \pmod 9, a^3+a+1\equiv 0 \pmod 9\\
a=8 \pmod 9, a^3+a+1\equiv 8 \pmod 9 $

so the only cases possible greater than a=b=1, is if a, is 7 mod 9, and b>1 . plugging that in we get:

$(9j+7)^3+(9j+7)+1 = 729j^3 + 1701j^2 + 1332j + 351$ ( done with PARI/GP)  which reduces to 26j when done mod 27. Without j a multiple of 27, this won't be 0 mod 27 which $3^b$ is for b>2.